# Подключение к удаленной БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, visual-studio

Всем привет!

Подскажите, кто знает, как подключиться из VS 2012 к SQL SERVER 2008 r2.

Проблема такова:

Есть удаленный сервер БД 192.168.130.130, там есть нужная база. В VS я выбираю обозреватель серверов, ввожу нужные данные для подключения, и когда жму "Проверить соединение", то сразу выскакивает ошибка, как на скрине:

[image]

Имя пользователя прописано в этой БД такое же, как я и ввожу. Но почему-то нет коннекта.
Может, я что-то не учел. Фаерволл выключен.

Comment: А пароль указан?

Comment: Там без пароля доступ

Comment: "Serg" это случайно не учетная запись windows?

Comment: А на сервере разрешен доступ без пароля с других машин?

Comment: Не, Serg - это просто логин на Sql 2008, а вот насчет логина без пароля я не знаю? А где это можно узнать?

Comment: Просто попробуйте завести пароль и им воспользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая распространенная ошибка, это если у вас в SQL Server настроена авторизация по Windows логину, а авторизация по логину-паролю отключена. В таком случае вам поможет включение смешанной авторизации. Как это сделать, кратко описано в статье: [Изменение режима авторизации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188670(v=sql.105).aspx).

Если это не помогло, то проверьте, разрешен ли доступ к SQL Server с удаленных машин, ведь он у вас на другом компьютере. Как быстро настроить удаленный доступ к БД описано здесь: [Remote connection to SQL Server DB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.105).aspx)